# Minecraft libraries download and launch from file json

Tags: .net, vb.net, minecraft

I have a problem in generate and download minecraft libraries and natives for windows.

from:

```
<package>:<name>:<version>
```

to:

```
<package>/<name>/<version>/<name>-<version>
```

please help!

Json file:

```
{
  "id": "1.8.8",
  "time": "2015-07-27T12:31:28+02:00",
  "releaseTime": "2015-07-27T12:31:28+02:00",
  "type": "release",
  "minecraftArguments": "--username ${auth_player_name} --version ${version_name} --gameDir ${game_directory} --assetsDir ${assets_root} --assetIndex ${assets_index_name} --uuid ${auth_uuid} --accessToken ${auth_access_token} --userProperties ${user_properties} --userType ${user_type}",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "name": "oshi-project:oshi-core:1.1"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.dev.jna:jna:3.4.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.dev.jna:platform:3.4.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.ibm.icu:icu4j-core-mojang:51.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.6"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:codecjorbis:20101023"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:codecwav:20101023"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:libraryjavasound:20101123"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:librarylwjglopenal:20100824"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:soundsystem:20120107"
    },
    {
      "name": "io.netty:netty-all:4.0.23.Final"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.google.guava:guava:17.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
    },
    {
      "name": "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.jinput:jinput:2.0.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.jutils:jutils:1.0.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.mojang:authlib:1.5.21"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.mojang:realms:1.7.28"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3"
    },
    {
      "name": "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.0-beta9"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.0-beta9"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.4-nightly-20150209",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl_util:2.9.4-nightly-20150209",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:2.9.4-nightly-20150209",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ],
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.2-nightly-20140822",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl_util:2.9.2-nightly-20140822",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:2.9.2-nightly-20140822",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ],
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.jinput:jinput-platform:2.0.5",
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tv.twitch:twitch:6.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "tv.twitch:twitch-platform:6.5",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "linux"
          }
        }
      ],
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows-${arch}",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tv.twitch:twitch-external-platform:4.5",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow",
          "os": {
            "name": "windows"
          }
        }
      ],
      "natives": {
        "windows": "natives-windows-${arch}"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "mainClass": "net.minecraft.client.main.Main",
  "minimumLauncherVersion": 14,
  "assets": "1.8"
}
```

example:

```
oshi-project:oshi-core:1.1
```

to:

```
oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar
```

and link on [libraries.minecraft.net *(JAR file)*](https://libraries.minecraft.net/oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar)

download link from mojang:

```
https://libraries.minecraft.net/<package>/<name>/<version>/<name>-<version>.jar
```

Comment: json is serialized **data** not just a fancy string. If you cant deserialize it, parse it:  `Dim jData = JObject.Parse(jstr)` then `Dim oshiInfo = jData("libraries")(0)("name").ToString.Replace(":"c, "/"c)` extracts and formats the item to `oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [Plutonix's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202624/minecraft-libraries-download-and-launch-from-file-json/32204138#comment52295621_32202624), I wrote another code which **should work better**. (I didn't know that JSON was serialized data).

**To run the following code**, you have to **install [Json.NET framework for .NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)** (using NuGet Packages is the better way), and to **import** `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` (`Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`).

```
Dim Libraries As New List(Of List(Of String))

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'The path of your json file.
    Dim FilePath As String = "C:\Users\Drarig29\Desktop\File.json"

    'Parses the your json file.
    Dim FileData = JObject.Parse(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FilePath))

    For Each Library In FileData("libraries")

        'The extracted library (<package>:<name>:<version>).
        Dim ExtractedLibrary As String = CStr(Library("name"))

        'The extracted under splitted by ":" form.
        'LibrarySplitted(0) = <package>
        'LibrarySplitted(1) = <name>
        'LibrarySplitted(2) = <version>
        Dim LibrarySplitted() As String = ExtractedLibrary.Split(CChar(":"))

        Dim Package As String = LibrarySplitted(0) '<package>
        Dim Name As String = LibrarySplitted(1) '<name>
        Dim Version As String = LibrarySplitted(2) '<version>

        'The string with the slashes (<package>/<name>/<version>/<name>-<version>).
        Dim WithSlashes As String = CreateWithSlashesString(Package, Name, Version)

        'The link (https://libraries.minecraft.net/<package>/<name>/<version>/<name>-<version>.jar).
        Dim Link As String = CreateLink(Package, Name, Version)

        Dim AllTheForms As New List(Of String)
        AllTheForms.Add(ExtractedLibrary)
        AllTheForms.Add(WithSlashes)
        AllTheForms.Add(Link)

        Libraries.Add(AllTheForms)
    Next
End Sub

'Creates a string with slashes (<package>/<name>/<version>/<name>-<version>).
Private Function CreateWithSlashesString(Package As String, Name As String, Version As String) As String
    Return Package & "/" & Name & "/" & Version & "/" & Name & "-" & Version
End Function

'Creates a web link to the library.
Private Function CreateLink(Package As String, Name As String, Version As String) As String
    Return "https://libraries.minecraft.net/" & Package & "/" & Name & "/" & Version & "/" & Name & "-" & Version
End Function
```

Once it's done, you can **access each item** (`ExtractedLibrary`, `WithSlashes`, or `Link`) **of each library by doing** `Libraries(<library's index>)(item's index)`.

For example, if you want to **get all the libraries' link**, you can do this :

```
For Each Library In Libraries
    'Library(0) corresponds to the name of the library.
    'Library(1) corresponds to the "WithSlashes" string of the library.
    MsgBox(Library(2)) 'Library(2) corresponds to the link of the library.
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code :

```
Dim Libraries As New List(Of List(Of String))

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'The path of your json file.
    Dim FilePath As String = "C:\Users\Drarig29\Desktop\File.json"

    'Gets all the json file content.
    Dim FileContent As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FilePath)

    'Gets only the libraries.
    FileContent = FileContent.Substring(FileContent.IndexOf("  ""libraries"": ["))

    Dim NextLineIsOsName As Boolean = False

    For Each Line In ReadAllLines(FileContent)
        If Line.Contains("""name"":") Then
            If NextLineIsOsName Then
                NextLineIsOsName = False
            Else
                'The extracted library (<package>:<name>:<version>).
                Dim ExtractedLibrary As String = Line.Split({"""name"": """}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1).Replace("""", "").Replace(",", "")

                'The extracted under splitted by ":" form.
                'LibrarySplitted(0) = <package>
                'LibrarySplitted(1) = <name>
                'LibrarySplitted(2) = <version>
                Dim LibrarySplitted() As String = ExtractedLibrary.Split(CChar(":"))

                Dim Package As String = LibrarySplitted(0) '<package>
                Dim Name As String = LibrarySplitted(1) '<name>
                Dim Version As String = LibrarySplitted(2) '<version>

                'The string with the slashes (<package>/<name>/<version>/<name>-<version>).
                Dim WithSlashes As String = Package & "/" & Name & "/" & Version & "/" & Name & "-" & Version

                'The link (https://libraries.minecraft.net/<package>/<name>/<version>/<name>-<version>.jar).
                Dim Link As String = "https://libraries.minecraft.net/" & Package & "/" & Name & "/" & Version & "/" & Name & "-" & Version

                Dim AllTheForms As New List(Of String)
                AllTheForms.Add(ExtractedLibrary)
                AllTheForms.Add(WithSlashes)
                AllTheForms.Add(Link)

                Libraries.Add(AllTheForms)
            End If
        ElseIf Line.Contains("""os"": {") Then
            NextLineIsOsName = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function ReadAllLines(value As String) As List(Of String)
    If value Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    Using StringRdr As New StringReader(value)
        While StringRdr.Peek() <> -1
            Dim line As String = StringRdr.ReadLine
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) Then
                lines.Add(line)
            End If
        End While
    End Using

    Return lines
End Function
```

Once it's done, you can **access each item** (`ExtractedLibrary`, `WithSlashes`, or `Link`) **of each library by doing** `Libraries(<library's index>)(item's index)`.

For example, if you want to **get all the libraries' link**, you can do this :

```
For Each Library In Libraries
    'Library(0) corresponds to the name of the library.
    'Library(1) corresponds to the "WithSlashes" string of the library.
    MsgBox(Library(2)) 'Library(2) corresponds to the link of the library.
Next
```

Comment: i have a problem with "filecontent = filecontent.substring .... "
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @MateuszBagiskiCzR It must be that your json file is not like the one you wrote in your question...

Comment: @MateuszBagiskiCzR System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException means that one of the integers in the `Substring method` is out of the string length.

Comment: @MateuszBagiskiCzR **Please give me your json file**. Upload it somewhere and give me the link.

Comment: this json in the question.

Comment: Replace the line `FileContent = FileContent.Substring(...` by `FileContent = FileContent.Substring(FileContent.IndexOf("  ""libraries"": ["))`. After that, it should work...